# Transaction confirmed by network but never showed up in bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've sent a large amount of coins to [1K7SzBTPGyyEtWsudwHpjg31LjrPf17qr4](http://blockchain.info/address/1K7SzBTPGyyEtWsudwHpjg31LjrPf17qr4) but my bitcoin-qt client (V. 4.7.4) doesn't show any balance.

1) Under the "Receive coins" tab it shows the same address
2) The client is synced and up to date
3) Under the "Overview" tab it shows 0.00BTC for both "Balance" and "Unconfirmed"
4) Under the "Transactions" tab it shows no transactions
4) http://blockchain.info shows 278 Confirmations.

Any ideas? I am getting real worried now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Launch the client from the command line with -rescan and it will recompute the balances for all addresses in your wallet.

For Windows:

```
C:\> Bitcoin-Qt -rescan
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Shut down app
2) Start it in the command prompt as follows: bitcoin-qt -rescan
3) Wait for the process to finish as this may take a while