# Bitcoin wallet not updating balance

Tags: wallet, bitcoind

My bitcoind wallet does not update the balance, I tried with two different wallet. It shows the correct balance on BlockChain.info.

I have tried the bitcoind -rescan solution given  in :[Transaction confirmed by network but never showed up in bitcoin-qt](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/transaction-confirmed-by-network-but-never-showed-up-in-bitcoin-qt)

However, the balance still shows as 0.

Machine : Ubuntu Linux
Bitcoin Version : 80600

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is your blockchain download complete? `-rescan`ing while the blockchain is still being downloaded will not achieve anything.

Comment: Well I was using the server for a month with no issues.  It used to rarely go down, so that last time that it went down I started it again, but there was no Balance in the wallet.

Comment: Which server do you mean? And... are you sure you didn't accidentally delete your wallet.dat or something?